# What is the purpose of liftIO?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code snippet from internet:

```
calculateLength :: LengthMonad Int
calculateLength = do
  -- all the IO operations have to be lifted to the IO monad in the monad stack
  liftIO $ putStrLn "Please enter a non-empty string: "
  s <- liftIO getLine
  if null s
    then throwError "The string was empty!"
    else return $ length s
```

and could not understand, why the author use `liftIO`?

What is the purpose of `liftIO`?

It is defined as follows:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadIO m where
    -- | Lift a computation from the 'IO' monad.
    liftIO :: IO a -> m a
```

Is it possible to lift `IO a -> [a]`? It looks like natural transformation.

Comment: You run a `IO a` in an `MonadIO m => m a`. For example a Yesod `Handler`.

Comment: It is not possible to use it with `IO a -> [a]`, since `[]` is not an instance of `MonadIO`.

Comment: Awesome. Why the author use `liftIO` above? What is point?

Comment: Because it looks like the `LengthMonad` (https://github.com/haskell/mtl/blob/master/Control/Monad/Error.hs#L129) is just a "monad transformer". They aim to wrap the `IO` monad in an `EitherT String` to run with errors (that is the purpose of `throwError`). Now since this is working with an `EitherT String IO`, we can not just use `IO a`s in the `do` block. We need something to "lift" these to an `EitherT String IO`.

Comment: @zero_coding It is simply a generalisation of the `IO` monad, and that is useful in itself. But when you say "what is the point" you seem to be searching for some other answer, which you have not elucidated. Please explain what you mean by "what is the point".

Comment: The "point" is that `putStrLn "..."` doesn't typecheck, but `liftIO $ putStrLn "..."` does. Are you asking why that is true?

Comment: @chepner `putStrLn "..."` does not get typechecked?

Comment: @zero_coding, "does not typecheck" is another way of saying "fails the typechecking phase". That is, if you use `putStrLn` there without `liftIO` you will get a type error.

Comment: @liqui I've got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`IO` operations like `getLine, putStrLn "..."` only work inside the `IO` monad. Using them inside any other monad will trigger a type error.

Still, there are many monads `M` which are defined in terms of `IO` (e.g. `StateT Int IO`, and apparently your `LengthMonad` as well) and because of that they allow `IO` actions to be converted into `M`-actions, and executed as such.

However, we need a conversion for each `M`:

```
convertIOintoM1 :: IO a -> M1 a 
convertIOintoM2 :: IO a -> M2 a
convertIOintoM3 :: IO a -> M3 a
...
```

Since this is cumbersome, the library defines a typeclass `MonadIO` having such conversion function, so that all the functions above can be named `liftIO` instead.

In practice, `liftIO` is used each time one wants to run `IO` actions in another monad, provided such monad allows for it.